# dom-to-image doesn't support some css styles like maskImg,but i have to use it,how can i make it?

Tags: javascript, css, image, dom, vuejs3

This is part of .vue, dom-to-image is a npm package, is used to translate html dom to images.

```
<div ref="product" class="w-[400px] h-[400px]">
  <img
    :src="baseLink.bgone"
    class="absolute w-[400px] h-[400px]"
    style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%"
  />
  <div
    @mousedown="holdDown"
    @mouseup="holdUp"
    @mousemove="handleMouseMove"
    @wheel="handleWheel"
    class="absolute w-[400px] h-[400px] left-0 top-0 imgdiv"
    :style="{
      backgroundSize: `${adjustS}%`,
      backgroundPosition: `${adjustX}px ${adjustY}px`,
      backgroundImage: 'url(' + uploadedImageUrl + ')',
      maskImage: 'url(' + baseLink.bgtwo + ')',
      maskSize: 'contain',
      maskPosition: 'center',
      maskRepeat: 'no-repeat',
    }"
  ></div>
</div>
```

I want to use dom-to-image to translate the box into img, but dom-to-image seems not support maskImg and other maskstyle, how can I fix it?

I want to make a div which can diy by the users, users can move the backgroundimg and control the scale, but the background is cut by another mask-img, I have tried html2tocanvas and dom-to-image, both of them don't support css like masksize, maskposition and so on.

Comment: @PeterB https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

Comment: _"how can i fix it"_ - I doubt there's an easy way to do that. The library works by "painting" your content onto a canvas element - and has to "apply" any formatting effects itself, while doing so. So not only would you have to find a point to add your own functionality into this process; you would have to implement the "math" behind whatever the operation is - masking, blurring, etc. - yourself as well.

Comment: These seems to be a related feature request issue on their Github page. The most recent comments seem hopeful. There was apparently a merge a while back related to the feature.
https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image/issues/297

Comment: Thank you, this possibly will be helpful for me with the issue! @lostime

Comment: nice issue,thank you